# DSDM Atern framework?

Tags: dsdm-atern

How does the DSDM Atern framework enable developers to integrate prototyping and testing into the system development life cycle.

I know this is not relevant to this website but i would appreciate any info you can provide as well as links to online material books etc to answer this question.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

yes by using the DSDM Atern 8 principle and 4 main technique, that make developers to integrate prototyping and testing into the system development life cycle.

here are some dsdm reference link

http://www.dsdm.org/

http://www.dsdm.org/wp-content/uploads/.../Sample-questions-Atern.pdf

http://www.dsdm.org/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/Sample-questions-Atern.pdf

http://www.agilexp.com/presentations/DSDMexplained.pdf

http://agile2007.agilealliance.org/downloads/presentations/DotTudor_1074.pdf

http://www.mediafire.com/?ttre3i91i33zzn2

there are several of DSDM resources available in net